# Documentation on component's metadata

Tags: sapui5

Documentations on UI5 components describe very well the meta data sections for `properties`, `aggregations` and `events`. But looking at the source code of standard UI5 controls there are more keywords used: `interfaces`, `libraries`, `publicMethods` and `keys`. Is there a complete documentations on the metadata section and the keywords there? I found this: `component.js` File - User Interface Add-On for SAP NetWeaver - SAP Library . But I think it's outdated and not very detailed

KR,
Nico

Answer (score 2):

A component is based on a ManagedObject (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html) which itself is based on an Object (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.Object.html)
You can find the available metadata properties in the respective API documentation. Additionally the component has additional component specific metadata properties. Theses are:

- **includes** (css, javascript files that should be used in the component)
- **dependencies** (external dependencies)

  - **libs** (array of required libraries)
  - **components** (components which are needed)
  - **ui5version**
- **library** (inherited from ManagedObject, if omitted, the current package is automatically retrieved)